# Why do we need hash if we already have ETag for cache strategy in front-end apps?

Tags: caching, hash, etag

I know that `webpack` can bundle files with some hash values, like `contenthash`,`chunkhash`, etc. It's good for browser cache and better UE, but as far as I know, the HTTP header - `ETag` is also doing the same thing. Can we just use ETag for cache and make all filenames without hash in it ?

Comment: See here: [ETag vs webpack's hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52666563/etag-vs-webpacks-hash).